# React - Each child in a list should have a unique “key” prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, key

I am working on a React Web Application Where I fetch and display student data from an API and I keep getting the error,

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Accordion`

Accordion.js being one of my components of my Web Application

Any Help to fix this issue would be appreciated :)

I have tried passing a key prop with an id to the Accordion component from a parent component, but that did not seem to work. Could it be that I need to pass a key in my test score paragraph?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 23

Make the following change

```
<p
```

To

```
<p key={`${i}-stats`}
```

The issue is simple. React needs to identify each sibling node uniquely and thus it asks you to pass key prop to sibling nodes when returning array or iterating over a lost to return component/view.

Comment: Thank You! Fixed the issue and I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: @Debug you can mark that accepted, it will save me and everyone else time.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not recommended** to use counter *(0, 1, 2...)* as your **key** when populating children.
You should use **uuid()** or item's **self-identifier**.